# Passing an array from PhP to jQuery using JSON and $.ajax

Tags: php, jquery, ajax, json, response

First off, I apologise since this is my first time working with JSON.

My website has a client script that requests person data from the server. The server first queries the database (using mysql and mysqli) and then returns the data (names, ages, etc.) to the client side.

Specifically, I want to pass an associative array from the PhP side to the client side.

After doing some research, I decided to do this with AJAX JSON calls.

The ***client side*** call is done like this:

```
var person_id = $('#my_text_box').val();

$.ajax({
 url: 'php/upload/my_server_script.php',
 method: 'POST',                                 
 data: {id: person_id},
 dataType: 'json',
 cache: false,
 success: function(response_data)
 {
   alert(response_data['name']); //The server should return an associative array
   console.log(response_data);
 },
 error: function(jqXHR, textStatus, errorThrown) 
 {
  console.log(arguments);
  console.log(jqXHR.responseText);
  console.log('Error: ' + errorThrown + ' ' + textStatus + ' ' + jqXHR);
 }
});
```

The **server side** calls a method that will query the database and give the details of the person with the requested ID.

$id = $_POST['id'];

function getPersonData($id)
{
    $personData = array();

```
(1 - Connect and SELECT name FROM Persons WHERE id = {$id}
 2 - Fill the $personData array with result row 
 3 - Name will be saved in $personData['name'])

return json_encode($personData);
```

The AJAX call fails with the error **500 - Internal Server Error**. When I check the contents of the server response on the browser (On Chrome, Network tab), it says there is no response (This request has no response data available).

The thing is, ***this code works perfect locally***. But when I upload it to my cloud web server, the only AJAX calls in my website that fail are the ones that use JSON as the format for the data being transferred. The other ones work fine.

A couple of things I've tried:

- First, **checking** if **the array** on the PhP side is empty or built with errors. It's not, all the correct values are there;
- Second, including **application/json** to the cloud web server **mime.type** file (It's Apache);
- Then, including a *header('Content-Type: application/json');* in my server-side script.
- Also, adding "*contentType: 'application/json*' " to the client-side **$.ajax**.

None of these four worked. What could I be forgetting?

**Note**: The browser's log reads as follows:

```
Arguments[3]
0: Object
1: "error"
2: "Internal Server Error"
callee: function (jqXHR, textStatus, errorThrown)
length: 3
__proto__: Object
*(url of my script file)*

Error: Internal Server Error error [object Object] ^
```

**Note #2**: **Full PhP** code:

```
//Fetch persondata for a specific ID, and encode the data in an array in JSON format
function JSONSelectPersonDataFromID($ID)
{   
        $personData = array();  //Array or array with results

        //If querysuccess, commit. Else, rollback
        $querySuccess = True;

        //This method opens connection with root user
        $conn = OpenDBConn();

        $conn->autocommit(False);

        try
        {
         if($videoID > 0)
         {
           $sql = "SELECT name FROM Persons WHERE id={$id}";

                //Debugging
                //echo $sql . "<br>";

                $persons = mysqli_query($conn, $sql);

                if(mysqli_connect_errno($conn))
                {
                    $querySuccess = False;
                }


                if(isset($persons ) && (count($persons ) > 0))
                {
                    //Loop through every scene  
                    $personData = $persons ->fetch_array(MYSQLI_ASSOC);
                }
                else
                {
                    return null;
                }
            }
            else
            {
                $querySuccess = False;
            }
        }
        catch(Exception $e)
        {
            $querySuccess = False;
        }

        if(!$querySuccess)
        {
         //Rollback
         $conn->rollback();
         die("Transaction failed");
        }
        else
        {
         //Commit
         $conn->commit();
        }

        //Close the connection
        DBClose($conn);

        return json_encode($personData );
}
```

Comment: A `500 error` means an error has occured on the server side (your PHP script). Because it only happens when posting JSON I would hazard a guess that you are incorrectly manipulating the JSON. Without seeing your PHP code this is impossible to diagnose.

Comment: What versions of PHP do you use locally and on the server? The behaviour of json_encode may differ.

Comment: Thanks for the feedback - phpInfo() informs me that I'm using "PHP Version 5.5.3-1ubuntu2.1" on my web server.

Comment: I've added the full PhP code of the server side function to my original post.

Comment: Have you tried loading the php file in the browser like this: "my_server_script.php?id=x" which x is the id that you ware passing with AJAX and change the PHP code to use GET method instead of POST and see what happens?

Answer (score 1):

"Internal server error" means the server crashed somewhere but for security reasons the client only get that 500 error. Check the server's error log file, there should be the real origin of the error (some real error, file and line number). You should start there.

Comment: That's my best clue so far, but I'm having some annoying permission issues trying to open the error log right now.

Comment: just saw your redit... to make it easier to debug, you don't have to commit anything or use transactions if you are only doing a select, your code is too complex for something that simple, try to reduce the code to something simpler (remove all that commit rollback thing) so you can find your problem quicker, the error log would be the best anyway

Answer (score 0):

Does the PHP script that uses AJAX have permissions to read the other PHP Script?

Comment: Yes. I tried removing the JSON format and the AJAX worked fine.

Comment: It is. It works perfect locally, just not when I test it live.

Comment: Try showing the errors on your php file. Use error_reporting(E_ALL); at the beginning of your PHP File and use Firebug to see what it shows. REMEMBER: Reporting errors will make your JSON returned useless as it will return a string + JSON. Show me if it shows errors.